# JS prototype returns prototype code

Tags: javascript, prototype

```
Array.prototype.last = function() { if(this.length !=0) return this[this.length-1]; }
myarray = new Array(1,2,3);
  for(var i in myarray){
  alert(i+'='+myarray[i]);
}
```

When the above code executes, it correctly alerts each loop, but then at the end another alert pops up with the source of the Array.prototype.last method.

This happens whenever I define any prototype method and I just don't know why !

So I get alerts for: 0=1,1=2,2=3 and then one for:

```
last=function () {
  if (this.length != 0) {
    return this[this.length - 1];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the `for-in` statement *enumerates* object properties, included the inherited ones.

That's one of the reasons why using the `for-in` statement with arrays or *array-like* objects is considered a bad practice.

Other reasons include that the order of enumeration is not guaranteed by the specification, this means that the index properties might not be visited in the numeric order, for example:

```
var a = [];
a[1] = 'b';
a[0] = 'a'

for (var prop in a) { console.log(i); }
```

Most browsers will detect you are trying to *iterate* over an array, and the properties will be visited in the numeric order, but in IE, the properties will be enumerated in the order that they were created, `1` and then `0`.

Also is known that the `for-in` statement can be slower than a simple sequential loop, because as you know now, it needs to introspect the whole prototype chain of the object, to enumerate the inherited members.

As a general recommendation, always use a sequential loop to *iterate* this kind of objects.

See also:

- [Enumeration VS Iteration](http://dhtmlkitchen.com/?category=/JavaScript/&date=2007/10/21/&entry=Iteration-Enumeration-Primitives-and-Objects)

Comment: Ahh, well I guess it's obvious when you know, but I find for(var in array) to be faster to write than for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++).

Comment: @Crankshaft: you can use jQuery $.each() i.e $.each(myarray,function(index,value){alert(value);}) to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is why you never use `for(idx in anArray){...}` in javascript the for...in loop iterates over *all* the properties in the `object`, and an `Array` is just an `object` in JS, you added a new property to all instances of `Array` so it appears as one of the indexes in the for loop.

with arrays generally you should do:

```
for(var i=0 ; i< anArray.length ; i++){
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: To be more precise, he added a property to Array's prototype which is enumerable and inherited by every instance of Array.  Bit of a clarification between that and "adding a property to every instance".

Comment: @Ken, is there? Think of it this way, by adding it to the prototype is this property not available from all present and future instances of `Array`? The semantics of prototypes in JS are such that, I don't see that statement as incorrect or misleading.

Comment: When I first read "new property to all instances of Array" I saw potential ambiguity, e.g. between every instance actually having their own copy of tha value, versus inheriting it from one place in common.  Not everyone understands how prototypes work, so I don't like leaving room for (mis)interpretation ;)  You obviously knew what you were talking about, but not everyone might have gleaned it from your initial wording.  'sallimsayin.

Comment: But they _do_ all have their own copy (it may be a copy of a reference in the case of objects, but the 'slot' is not shared) once they are instantiated - try `Array.prototype.foo="bar"` then instantiating a couple of arrays and changing their `foo` value... they remain separate. If you use an object instead of a string you can share changes to members of that object because each `Array` has their own copy of a reference to the object (which can be confusing generally in JS - everything is pass by value... except objects)

Answer (score 0):

That is because last is a function which myarray derives from the prototype properties and is indexable. To avoid that you need to check hasOwnProperty i.e.:

```
for(var i in myarray)
{
  if(myarray.hasOwnProperty(i))
    alert(i+'='+myarray[i]); 
}
```

Comment: +1 for proper explanation of prototype inheritance and enumerability, and hasOwnProperty, but still, better yet is to steer clear of for...in for array iteration.

Comment: @Ken: Thanks. Agreed. @Someone:I am curious to know the reason for downvote.

Comment: Perhaps they thought I was too generous given the continued use of for...in for arrays. =/